# How to pass values in some text file (python) to a YAML file

Tags: python, yaml

I need to pass a value in a `python` file to a `yaml` file.

This is my `constants.py`

```
NAMESPACE = "bitesize-troubleshooter"
DEPLOYMENT_NAME = "deployment-test"
```

this is my `yaml` file

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: deployment-test-ingress
  namespace: //here I want to pass the NAMESPACE value
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: / 
    nginx.org/ssl-services: deployment-test-clusterip
spec:
  rules:
  - host: # empty in this case, but you could fill in the host here (we use the minikube IP instead)
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: deployment-test-clusterip
          servicePort: 80
```

the place in `yaml` where it says `namespace` should be assigned with the `NAMESPACE` constant in the python file.

Is there a way I can do this in yaml?

Comment: YAML does not describe a process, it only describes data. That means that you cannot *pass* anything to it. However, you can pass something to the process *loading* the YAML, so you should describe how the YAML is loaded.

Comment: Don't thank me, update your question to include information about how the YAML is loaded. You can get a solution more tailored to your use-case if you show how you process your YAML.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to rewrite the yaml, treating it as a template. There are many approaches to template substitution. For example, with this:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: deployment-test-ingress
  namespace: ${NAMESPACE} 
...

Also, I see you're working with Kubernetes yaml. Take a look at Helm, which adds this sort of configurability.
```

Python could call `envsubst` by launching an external process, or use   this Pypi  [library](https://pypi.org/project/envsubst/)  , or simply read in the yaml, and call `yaml_str.replace("${NAMESPACE}", namespace)` .

Comment: @ToRrent If you like the answer, please upvote and/or accept.

Answer (score 0):

Install pyyaml package if you don't have it already: `pip install pyyaml`.

Then update the NAMESPACE and DEPLOYMENT_NAME parameters in your yaml file as follows:

```
import yaml

NAMESPACE, DEPLOYMENT_NAME = "bitesize-troubleshooter", "deployment-test"
yaml_file, params = "your.yaml", None

with open(yaml_file) as f:
    params = yaml.safe_load(f)

params['metadata']['namespace'] = NAMESPACE
params['metadata']['name']      = DEPLOYMENT_NAME

with open(yaml_file, 'w') as f:
    yaml.safe_dump(params, f)
```